# Place a Vertical Line Between the Two Pages with pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}

Tags: line, vertical, pgfpages, pgfpagesuselayout

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[14pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}
\usepackage{lipsum,tocloft}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{TOC ENTRY 1.}
%\cleardoublepage

\newpage
\lipsum[1-2]
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{TOC ENTRY 2.}
%\cleardoublepage

\newpage
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

[image]

QUESTION: How may I insert a visible vertical line extending for the length of the page exactly in the middle of each 2-page dispay when using `\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}`?

Thank you.