# Why TOC with \pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1} Displays Incorrect Page Numbers

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, tocloft, pgfpages, pgfpagesuselayout

This question is a follow-up to [Place a Vertical Line Between the Two Pages with pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671430/place-a-vertical-line-between-the-two-pages-with-pgfpagesuselayout2-on-1)

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[14pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
%\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}
\usepackage{lipsum,tocloft}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{TOC ENTRY 1.}
%\cleardoublepage

\newpage
\lipsum[1-2]
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{TOC ENTRY 2.}
%\cleardoublepage

\newpage
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

which produces a Table of Contents with correct page numbers:

[image]

However, when I run the above code with `\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}`, I get a Table of Contents with *incorrect* page numbers:

[image]

QUESTION: Does anyone know why the TOC when using `\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}` displays incorrect page numbers; and, how I may correct it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say why this is happening, but there is  a workaround.

[image: a]

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tocloft}

%**************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcounter{altpage}
\makeatletter
\def\addcontentsline#1#2#3{%
    \setcounter{altpage}{\thepage}%
    \addtocontents{#1}{\protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{\thealtpage}{}%
        \protected@file@percent}}
\makeatother
%***************************

\begin{document}
        
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{TOC ENTRY 1.} %before a pseudo chapter ?
    \lipsum[1]  
    
    %\cleardoublepage
            
    \newpage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{TOC ENTRY 2.}%before a pseudo chapter ?
    \lipsum[1-8]            

    \newpage    
    \tableofcontents
    
\end{document}
```

I moved `\addcontentsline` before the text because I think this is where you want to mark the start of a pseudo chapter and also because being always at the beginning of a page will get the page number correctly.

Comment: Thank you; but I have a question---is `\protected@file@percent` needed? When I run your code as is, I get an "undefined control sequence" error", although the correct output appears. But, when I comment out `\protected@file@percent`, everything seems to work fine for me.

Comment: I should be able to check back in about 90 minutes, as I will be away from my computer till then.

Comment: @mlchristians The `protected@file@percent` is part of the original definition of `\addcontentsline` used by LaTeX base. I tested with pdflatex and lualatex. Try the code as it is with a new filename in your working directory. The code will run twice: first to make the `.toc` file and then to display the complete Contents page.

Comment: @mlchristians It looks that the command `\protected@file@percent` was introduced in a late 2018 release to solve some issues that will not be present in your case. So perhaps you can comment it out safely. I am using XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (MiKTeX 22.10) LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5

Comment: Many thanks Simon Dispa for your very helpful answer and comments.